# How to run a function multiple times and return different result python

Tags: python, django, random

I'm having a problem and I don't know if this is doable but what I wanted to do is call a function multiple times. The idea is I am generating a serial number for tickets, I have a function that generates a number which is 16 in length:

```
import random
import string

def random_number_generator(size=16, numbers=string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(numbers) for _ in range(size))
```

Now if I run this function like this `print(random_number_generator() * 4)` it will return something like this:

```
1234567890987654
1234567890987654
1234567890987654
1234567890987654
```

How do I make it to return different numbers instead of the same numbers?

Comment: Well, we are missing some code. What is `string.digits`?

Comment: @Fourier import string. its `'0123456789'`

Comment: @Fourier - https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.digits

Comment: @Sayse Thank you! I was under the impression the user wrote some custom class.

Comment: It’s outside the scope of Stack Overflow, but I would strongly recommend learning more Python, and programming as a whole.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way you using * 4 in print() just make it print the same result from the function 4 times. You can use something simple from python as a loop to run it x times:

```
for k in range(4):
   print(random_number_generator())
```

Because the number range so large there less likely to have repeat results, but you can use this to remove duplicate results

```
output = []
expected_results = []
for k in range(4):
   output.append(random_number_generator())

expected_results = list(dict.fromkeys(output))

print(expected_results)
```

Comment: Alternately, `print([random_number_generator() for _ in range(4)])`

Comment: Never knew it will be this simple. Worked for me. Thanks

Comment: closer equivalent would be `print(*[r_n_g() for _ in range(4)], sep='\n')`

Comment: @Martins if it worked for your situation then you can accept the answer

Comment: advice taken @LinhNguyen

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(4):
    print(random_number_generator())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just loop through your function and append generated numbers to an empty list.

```
number_of_tickets = 10
ticket_serial_numbers = []
for i in range(number_of_tickets):
    serial_number = random_number_generator()
    ticket_serial_numbers.append(serial_number)
```

Comment: very useful. Thanks.